# Derivative operator is closed with $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Why is the derivative operator $D=\frac{d}{dx}:H^1(R)\subset L^2(R) \rightarrow L^2(R)$ a closed operator? (using the $L^2$ norms)

Comment: Well what do you get when you apply the closed graph theorem to its graph?

Comment: @user159517 My original question is why its graph is closed

Comment: Though the context may appear to be different, your question is really equivalent to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272615/heisenberg-inequality-proof/2276027?noredirect=1#comment4681999_2276027

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the closed graph theorem, let $f_n$ converge to $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $g_n$ to $g$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where $f_n' = g_n$. This means in particular that $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $H^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and therefore converges against an element in $H^1$, which can only be $f$, so we must have $f' =g$.

If you don't want to use completeness of $H^1$, let's assume WLOG that $f_n$ converges pointwise almost everyhwere. Each $f_n$ is absolutely continuous, so it makes sense to write

$$f_{n}(x+h) - f_{n}(x) = \int_{x}^{x+h} g_{n}(t) ~dt$$

We find

$$\int_{x}^{x+h}|g_n - g| dt \leq \sqrt{\int_{x}^{x+h}1^2 dt}\sqrt{\int_{x}^{x+h} |g_n - g|^2 dt} \leq \sqrt{h}\|g_n - g\|_{L^2}$$

This argument shows that the right hand side of the first formula above converges against $\int_{x}^{x+h} g(t)~dt$. Taking the limit $n \to \infty$ in this formula, we find (outside a set of measure zero)

$$f(x+h) - f(x) = \int_{x}^{x+h} g(t) dt$$

which shows $f' = g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I think your statement is not correct as I don't think $H^1$ is Banach with respect the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @inquisitor it isn't, but it is complete with respect to the $H^1$-norm...