# Show that $T:L^2(\mathbb{R})\supset D(T)\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $Tf= f'$ is closeable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have the following exercise:
Let $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Define $T:\mathcal{H}\supseteq D(T)\to \mathcal{H}$ by
$$
Tf = f',\quad f \in D(T) := C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})
$$
where $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of smooth functions with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $T$ is closeable.

My approach would be to let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a sequence of functions with $f_n\to 0$ in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm, such that $Tf_n = f_n'\to g$ also in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm. Then, I would need to show that $g=0$. This makes sense if I can say that the limit of the derivatives $f_n'$ is the derivative of the limit of $f_n$, $0'= 0$, but I have no idea how to show this since $f_n\to 0$ in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ norm, so not uniformly.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273854/derivative-operator-is-closed-with-l2-norm

Comment: The question as asked has a domain problem.  Not all functions in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ are square-integrable or have a square-integrable derivative.  If you fix the domain problem, the simplest way to go about it is use integration-by-parts to show that $iT$ is symmteric where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  Any symmetric operator is closable.

Comment: @ChadK I think I am not yet allowed to use symmetry of operators and derived properties thereof, as we have not introduced that concept in our lecture, yet. I see the problem you mention with the domain, the problem statement on the exercise sheet is written exactly like that so I assume that what is actually meant is $C_0^\infty\cap L^2$.

Comment: @NielsSlotboom:  $f$ and $f'$ both need to be assumed in $C_0^\infty\cap L^2$.

Comment: @ChadK I just remembered: We were told that $C^\infty_0$ meant the set of smooth functions with compact support, so they are $L^2$ integrable. How would I prove it without making use of symmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $\langle iTf,g\rangle=\langle f,iTg\rangle$ for all $f,g\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$.

Now assume $f,h_f,h_g\in L^2$, and $f_n, g_n\in C_c^\infty$ such that $f_n\to f$, $g_n\to f$, $Tf_n\to h_f$ and $Tg_n\to h_g$.  If $\psi\in C_c^\infty$ then
$$
\langle iTf_n,\psi\rangle=\langle f_n,iT\psi\rangle\rightarrow\langle f,iT\psi\rangle
$$
and since $iTf_n\to ih_f$ then also $\langle iTf_n,\psi\rangle\to\langle ih_f,\psi\rangle=\langle h_f,i\psi\rangle$.  So $\langle f,T(i\psi)\rangle=\langle h_f,i\psi\rangle$ for all $\psi\in C_c^\infty$.

Doing the same with the sequence $g_n$ and $h_g$ you get $\langle f,T(i\psi)\rangle=\langle h_g,i\psi\rangle$ for all $\psi\in C_c^\infty$.  Therefore $\langle (h_f-h_g),i\psi\rangle=0$ for all $\psi\in C_c^\infty$.  Since $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$ it follows that $h_f-h_g=0$, so $h_f=h_g$ and that's what needs be shown for $T$ to be closable.

Edit: If you want to avoid the use of $i$, show instead that $\langle Tf,g\rangle=-\langle f,Tg\rangle$ and do the rest while keeping track of the minus sign.